# `strcpy` out of bounds to an array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I don't understand why I can do this:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

char a[1][100];

void main(void) {
    strcpy(a[0], "test1");
    strcpy(a[1], "test2");
    strcpy(a[6], "test3");

    printf("%s", a[0]);
    printf("%s", a[1]);
    printf("%s", a[6]);

}
```

Will return:

```
test1test2test3
```

In my understanding, when i do `char a[1][100]` I'm creating a 2d array, with 2 elements, `a[0]` and `a[1]`, each pointing to an array of 100 chars.
Why can I assign anything to `a[6]`? Shouldn't that be out of bounds? Where is this in memory?

Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: The C syntax may be misleading.. but actually you are getting a chunk of memory to store 100 `char` that starts at `a[0]`

Comment: You are invoking undefined behavior, it just so happens that your program owns that memory anyway (probably since you allocate a fairly large buffer) so you aren't getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: This is creating an array of one string 100 characters long. However the array length is only what is safely allocated.

Comment: You have a bug, so your code doesn't work the way you expect it to. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away.

Comment: i think the problem is more that the compiler doesn't tell him he has totally insane indices in his accesses to a. I'm not sure I blame him, as I can't get any compiler apart from IBM xlC to warn about that code

Comment: Curious: What did you expect to happen; expect the program to detect the bounds violation?  If code, when running, did complain, that implies the code checked the bounds.  That takes time.  C runs quickly without that safety net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you're creating a 2D array with only one element, `a[0]`. Both `a[1]` and `a[6]` are accessing memory that you don't own, and will cause undefined behavior. "Undefined" does not mean "will crash", it means "undefined", including the possibility that it works just as if you had allocated things properly. By chance, the memory you're using isn't conflicting with anything else, so there is no consequence of your error.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is out of bounds but what are you expecting to happen?

The `strcpy(a[6], "test3");` will overwrite a portion of the stack. Will it cause a problem? Probably. will it be immediately obvious? Probably not.

Comment: array `a` is declared in data segment, not in stack. ??

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't have any bounds checking, even at compile time. If you're lucky

```
int a[5];
a[10] = 10;
```

will generate a warning. In general it's a good idea to compile with as many warnings as your compiler will give you.

Sadly the only ones I can get from gcc on your code are that 'main must have a return type of int'. With IBM's compiler, I do get this:

```
"bad.c", line 8.14: 1506-1299 (W) The subscript 1 is out of range. The only valid subscript is 0.
"bad.c", line 8.14: 1506-1299 (W) The subscript 1 is out of range. The only valid subscript is 0.
"bad.c", line 9.14: 1506-1299 (W) The subscript 6 is out of range. The only valid subscript is 0.
"bad.c", line 9.14: 1506-1299 (W) The subscript 6 is out of range. The only valid subscript is 0.
"bad.c", line 12.20: 1506-1299 (W) The subscript 1 is out of range. The only valid subscript is 0.
"bad.c", line 13.20: 1506-1299 (W) The subscript 6 is out of range. The only valid subscript is 0.
```

At this point, as some of the comments note, you are in the realms of undefined behaviour. Because you created a HUGE array on the stack, nothing bad happens.

Other points:

C Arrays are 0 based. `a[1]` creates an array with one member, `a[0]`.

C 2 dimensional arrays are in fact one dimensional arrays. `int a[5][5]` allocates a space of 30 words and gives `a` the address of a[0][0]. a[x][y] is accessed by multiplying x by 5, adding y and looking at that location. Not by looking at the contents of a[x], and looking y locations on from that.